# User not granted for mysql database but still can query?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

Here is what I do to check grants for a specific user:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR mmuser1;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mmuser1@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mmuser1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*fesfesfesfes' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `shopping_mm`.* TO 'mmuser1'@'%'
```

However, if I do the following:

```
mysql -ummuser1 -p
```

I can acccess and query another database (sports). Also, when doing:

```
SELECT Db,User FROM db;
```

I can see this Db associated with this user.

How is it possible that is not showing in the Grants table?

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`SHOW GRANTS` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-grants.html):

> If you specify only the user name part of the account name, a host name part of `'%'` is used.

It is likely that you have granted permission to your user with an explicit hostname, e.g. `'mmuser1'@'localhost'`.  As documented later on the same page, this can be verified once connected:

> To list the privileges granted to the account that you are using to connect to the server, you can use any of the following statements:
>
> ```
> SHOW GRANTS;
> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
> ```

Or, alternatively, simply inspect [`CURRENT_USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user):

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. However, when I do this: ``select host, db, user, select_priv from mysql.db;`` I see that this user has access to a database with a specific ip 192.168.0.10. But, if I do ``SHOW GRANTS FOR 'marketmo_mmuser1'@'199.168.0.10';`` It will say that there is no such a grant defined. How is that possible?

Comment: @HommerSmith: The first octet is different in the two cases (192 vs 199) - is that a typo?  Also, the username is different (marketmo_mmuser1 vs mmuser1) - is that just a simplification?

Comment: Thats a typo yes... mmuser1 is correct as well as 192.

Comment: @HommerSmith: And what does `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` reveal?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a wildcard user that is usually default in Mysql is setup?

Any or %  for the user name or  host will allow any username/host permission to the DB, like in the picture below

You should remove these users that are usually default in MySQL

[image]

This picture is the default accounts that are installed with MYSQL , and all of them should be deleted as soon as you create a new user as none of them are secure,  they allow - any username USAGE access to the db's

Comment: I don't understand this. What do you mean a wildcard user?

Comment: -1 As documented under [`GRANT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html): "*MySQL does not support wildcards in user names*".

Comment: I'm not talking about GRANT...  If an "ANY" user exists , then will already be granted those permissions so GRANT under a specfic username wouldnt work

Comment: @StevenMartin: There is no such thing as an "ANY" user.

Comment: As far as you know , but you dont know. When you install MySQL for the first time, there is an ANY user and if you dont delete it , then ANY username is valid ,  Maybe you should read up before saying things dont exist!

http://serverfault.com/questions/280711/what-are-any-user-and-information-schema-on-mysql-server

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html - Anon user @ or ANY

Comment: @eggyal: MySQL ****DOES**** support widcards in usernames if you write DML directly into the mysql schema: Steven Martin did not fake that screenshot above.

Comment: @symcbean: Er, no.  MySQL uses `strcmp()` to [match authenticating users against table entries](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.6/view/head:/sql/sql_acl.cc?sort=date#L9909), which does not support wildcard pattern matching. A record with `User='%'` means that the username is a literal percentage character and nothing more. MySQL *does* however support **anonymous** users, to which an unrecognised username will fallback, but that is quite another matter entirely.  The MySQL documentation quoted above is completely correct: *wildcards are **not supported** in user names*.

Comment: However, anonymous users are [represented by the empty string `''`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.6/view/head:/sql/sql_acl.cc?sort=date#L9908) (whereupon `!acl_user_tmp->user` evaluates to true) and not by a percentage character, the string `"Any"` or anything else.  As I stated above, *there is no such thing as an "ANY" user*.  I cannot speak for the screenshot that Mr Martin has included in his post, as I do not recognise the UI: it's entirely possible that the User values of `'Any'` and/or `'%'` are a feature of that database client software.

Comment: Its PHPMYADMIN and yes it shows a blank anon user as ANY    - It still means that ANY username is valid until this anon user is deleted.

Comment: The default anon permission of `USAGE` allows such users to connect, but not to *do* anything.  It doesn't explain the observed behaviour.  Almost everything in this answer is wrong and I stand by my downvote and comments.

Comment: @eggyal: if that were true then NONE of the MySQL applications I support would work. If you don't believe me then try it for yourself.

Comment: @symcbean: I don't know to which bit of what I said you are referring, but I too have a not inconsiderable experience both developing and supporting applications that use MySQL and indeed working on the server source code itself.  I am quite comfortable that I know what I'm talking about, but by all means take this conversation elsewhere if you disagree.